# Live Agent for Service Cloud Console Problems

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console

We have rolled out Live Agent for Service Cloud Console and are having some intermittent problems.

Sometimes we will get an "insufficient privileges" error upon accepting a chat.  Other times a chat will get missed and it isn't clear why.  And yet other times chats will be dropped in mid-chat.  This happens 25-50% of the time, which is enough to make Live Agent for Service Cloud Console too unreliable for production use.

We have worked with salesforce support on this.  There are some known issues related to not switching tabs while the Service Cloud Console is open.  We are following these guidelines, but are still having these problems.

I'm curious if others are experiencing these problems as well.  If so, any ideas on how to fix them?

Answer (score 1):

I have also worked on Live Agent Product and experienced same sort of issues.

Some common rules i follow is as follows:

1)Check whether the Agent is assigned a Live Agent Licence by making sure Live Agent user check box is ticked for the user

2)You can integrate the Live Agent with Service Cloud Console and hence this will avoid the switching of the App

3)Always avoid use of your own CSS to customize the Chat window as we have seen lot of issues with this

If all fails last option is to raise a case with support and make them aware .

Answer (score 0):

We have had similar problems when we started using it in production.  This permissions issue dogged us for a long time and we worked closely with Support on that issue.  It still happens intermittently but the occasions are so few and far between now that it doesn't matter.  We however had a huge problem with chats disconnecting, seemingly randomly.  Worked with support for a month solving that issue and the culprit was found to be a meta-refresh tag on the page hosting the chatlet.